# Reading a jpg into BMP in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

When I try to read in a jpg into a BitmapImage in a windows phone 8 app, and I get the following error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException
```

I was reading up about it, and it told me that I need to check the Photo Capability in the app's manifest file, which I did. I still get the error.

My code to read in is:

```
System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage b = 
    new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(@"cat.jpg",         
    UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Are there any other causes for this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BitmapImage` object can only be constructed on the UI thread. You can do so using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage b = 
        new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(@"cat.jpg",         
        UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

});
```

Keep in mind that it's asynchronous, though, so your execution will need to continue within the lambda passed to BeginInvoke

Comment: How do people know these things... >.> THanks!!

Comment: Check the message on the `UnauthorizedAccessException` ;)